# Proguard Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, proguard

Does anyone know the keep statement that needs to be added to Proguard for Google Analytics?

I have this line right now but for some reason nothing is being reported...

```
 # google analytics, uncomment if using:
-keep class com.google.android.apps.analytics.PipelinedRequester$Callbacks
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a generic

```
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

in my proguard.cfg and Google Analytics works fine.

Try this. If this does not solve the problem, then your problem is not Proguard but rather a Google Analytics configuration or connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official proguard rules file in `aar` package, locate at:

> android-sdk-windows\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-analytics\x.x.x\play-services-analytics-x.x.x.aar

**proguard.txt:**

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

# Needed when building against the Marshmallow SDK
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

# Needed when building against pre-Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy
```

And you can see section **Create a ProGuard Exception** in this page for more detail: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup